# Error in the "net" module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to test a code in the node.js documentary but i have this problem:

net.js:951
      throw new TypeError('"port" option should be a number or string: ' +
      ^

TypeError: "port" option should be a number or string: null

My code is:

```
const http = require('http');
const net = require('net');
const url = require('url');

// Create an HTTP tunneling proxy
var proxy = http.createServer( (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('okay');
});
proxy.on('connect', (req, cltSocket, head) => {
  // connect to an origin server
  var srvUrl = url.parse("http://${req.url}");
  var srvSocket = net.connect(srvUrl.port, srvUrl.hostname, () => {
    cltSocket.write('HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established\r\n' +
                    'Proxy-agent: Node.js-Proxy\r\n' +
                    '\r\n');
    srvSocket.write(head);
    srvSocket.pipe(cltSocket);
    cltSocket.pipe(srvSocket);
  });
});

// now that proxy is running
proxy.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1', () => {

  // make a request to a tunneling proxy
  var options = {
      port: '1337',
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    method: 'CONNECT',
    path: 'www.google.com'
  };

  var req = http.request(options);
  req.end();

  req.on('connect', (res, socket, head) => {
    console.log('got connected!');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no port number in the path/url of the request, it's just 'www.google.com'. You will want to default to a port (e.g. 80) if there is no port defined in the path/url.

Additionally, you are using the wrong set of quotes for the value passed to `url.parse()`. You need backticks instead of normal quotes:

```
var srvUrl = url.parse(`http://${req.url}`);
```